# How to send an email from c# to Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetAllUsersName U = new GetAllUsersName();
    string Email = U.GetUSEREmail(TxtEmailPass.Text);

    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;


    mySmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Projects@gmail.com", "Pro123456789");
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("Projects@gmail.com", Email, "Password", "your password is:");



    mySmtpClient.Send(msg);

}
```

This is my code, but it keeps telling me:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. If this is a new account, make sure you change your password - at least once. Gmail may be looking for you to change password.

Comment: so all i have to do is to change the password ?

Comment: @kamalsaeed it can be a cause of the issue you are encountering, can you give it a go?

Comment: Same thing, I change it but nothing happen

Comment: Just to let you know :) , the problem was with the account, I fixed it, 
Thank you for your help :) <3

Comment: @kamalsaeed glad to be of help.